# Shell script to append string to the end of all CSV fields in 2nd column

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, shell, awk

I'm trying to write a BASH script that will append **:00:00** to the end of all values in the 2nd field of a CSV file.

I've tried reading through 'awk' man pages but I'm not understanding how I can complete this. Any help is appreciated!

#### Source file:

```
2012-02-29,00,Manhatten,New York,244
2012-02-29,01,Manhatten,New York,246
2012-02-29,02,Manhatten,New York,554
2012-02-29,03,Manhatten,New York,854
2012-02-29,04,Manhatten,New York,488
```

#### Result file:

```
2012-02-29,00:00:00,Manhatten,New York,244
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,246
2012-02-29,02:00:00,Manhatten,New York,554
2012-02-29,03:00:00,Manhatten,New York,854
2012-02-29,04:00:00,Manhatten,New York,488
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a command to filter the conversion:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," } (NF>=2) { $2=$2 ":00:00"; } (1)'
```

If you have a file `source.txt` which store source data and a file `result.txt` to be stored the output, following command will do:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," } (NF>=2) { $2=$2 ":00:00"; } (1)' source.txt >result.txt
```

If you have multiple input files, you can add them in arguments.
See [manpage of awk](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?awk) for more details.

Comment: Hi kamae, thanks for the reply. If I was using this in a script file, where would I include the input and output files?

i.e. `awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," } (NF>=2) { $2=$2 ":00:00"; } (1)', input.csv > output.csv`

Comment: @SirOracle, thank you for your comment. I added an example describing your comment.

Comment: The same, but a little bit shorter: awk -F, -v OFS=, '$2=$2":00:00"'

Answer (score 0):

One liner with perl

```
perl -F, -nae '$F[1].=":00:00";print join(",", @F);'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` as well (which would be my first choice) but using `awk` is fine too..

What you need is to extract value in each column, and just print them back, but while printing the second column, append your `:00:00`.

see this example, give it a try and get back if you have some specific questions:

```
$ cat a.txt
2012-02-29,00,Manhatten,New York,244
2012-02-29,01,Manhatten,New York,246
2012-02-29,02,Manhatten,New York,554
2012-02-29,03,Manhatten,New York,854
2012-02-29,04,Manhatten,New York,488
$ awk -F , '{print $1 "-" $2 "-" $3 "-" $4 "-" $5}' a.txt
2012-02-29 - 00 - Manhatten - New York - 244
2012-02-29 - 01 - Manhatten - New York - 246
2012-02-29 - 02 - Manhatten - New York - 554
2012-02-29 - 03 - Manhatten - New York - 854
2012-02-29 - 04 - Manhatten - New York - 488
$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/,/:00:00,/2' file
2012-02-29,00:00:00,Manhatten,New York,244
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,246
2012-02-29,02:00:00,Manhatten,New York,554
2012-02-29,03:00:00,Manhatten,New York,854
2012-02-29,04:00:00,Manhatten,New York,488
```

or this:

```
awk  '{sub(/,../,"&:00:00")}1' file
2012-02-29,00:00:00,Manhatten,New York,244
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,246
2012-02-29,02:00:00,Manhatten,New York,554
2012-02-29,03:00:00,Manhatten,New York,854
2012-02-29,04:00:00,Manhatten,New York,488
```